# Cordova iOS 8 Filereader onload/onloadend not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm using cordova plugins `file v1.3.2` and `file-transfer v0.5.0` to manage downloading a file from the internet and then reading it in the application.

The file download and all that works properly but for some reason the `FileReader` has stopped working. It all worked properly a few months ago. `onloadstart` does get run but `onload` nor `onloadend` ever get run.

This is my javascript code:

```js
var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/wines-1";
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(APP_CONFIG.tbDevDlUrl+"wine_data_dl.php?file=1");

console.log("[WORKER] Downloading wine file #1 to", fileURL);

fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent){
    if(progressEvent.lengthComputable){
        var percent = (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
        $("#backgroundNotification").find(".loading-bar").css("width", percent+"%");
    }
};
fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry){
        console.log("[WORKER] Wine file 1 download complete");

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("cdvfile://localhost/persistent/wines-1", gotFile, fail);

        function fail(e){
            console.log("[WORKER] FileSystem Error");
            console.log(e);
            deferred.reject();
        }

        function gotFile(fileEntry){
            console.log("[WORKER] Reached gotFile");
            fileEntry.file(function(file){
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    console.log("[WORKER] Successfully fetched local wines copy file 1 from FileSystem");
                    Wine.tmpData = JSON.parse(this.result);

                    self.updateWineDatabase()
                        .then(function (count) {
                             console.log("[WORKER] First file done. Processed", count, "wines");
                             Wine.tmpData = [];  // garbage management
                        });
                };

                reader.onerror = function(e){
                    console.log("[WORKER] Failed to read file 1");
                    console.log(e);
                    deferred.reject();
                };

                reader.error = function(e){
                    console.log("[WORKER] Failed to read file 1");
                    console.log(e);
                    deferred.reject();
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);
            })
        }
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("[WORKER] Failed to download wine file 1. source", error.source, "target", error.target, "code", error.code);
        deferred.reject();
    },
    false
);
```

I've also tried the apps Documents folder `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` but it didn't work from there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue. It was an invalid JSON file. So in the future when someone has problems reading json files with `FileReader`, make sure your JSON is valid.